How to configure external JDBC data source for a ee8 web application in Jetty 12 (migrated from Jetty 9)?
We recently upgraded from Jetty 9 to Jetty 12 and are trying to configure a JDBC data source externally (outside of the web application).
Following the Jetty 12 Operations Guide, I was able to set up the JDBC data source and bring the application up successfully. The data source was previously defined within JETTY_BASE/webapps/myapp.xml as shown below:
<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref refid="wac"/></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientConnectionPoolDataSource">
        <Set name="DatabaseName">ServDB</Set>
        <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
        <Set name="PortNumber">1529</Set>
        <Set name="User">xxx</Set>
        <Set name="Password">xxx</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
  <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase">webapps/myapp</Set>
</Configure>

Goal:
I am trying to move the data source configuration (bolded section above) to an external configuration file to separate the database configuration from the application.
What I Tried:
I moved the JDBC configuration into JETTY_BASE/etc/myapp.xml as follows:
<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref refid="wac"/></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientConnectionPoolDataSource">
        <Set name="DatabaseName">ServDB</Set>
        <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
        <Set name="PortNumber">1529</Set>
        <Set name="User">xxx</Set>
        <Set name="Password">xxx</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>

However, this setup didn’t work, and the application did not pick up the data source. The web application configuration in JETTY_BASE/webapps/myapp.xml now looks like this:
<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.ee8.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase">webapps/myapp</Set>
</Configure>

We are using an EE8 webapp. The following Jetty modules are enabled:
resources
logging-log4j2
deploy
ee8-servlet
plus
jndi
(among others)

Question:
How can I move the JDBC data source configuration from the web application and into an external configuration file like JETTY_BASE/etc/myapp.xml?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
